# c# XDocument XML format

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I had this xml :

```
<cats>
    <cat>
      <name>funycat_00</name>
      <category>funy</category>
      <link>/data/funy/funy_cat00</link>
    </cat>
    <cat>
      <name>funycat_01</name>
      <category>funy</category>
      <link>/data/funy/funy_cat01</link>
    </cat>
    <cat>
      <name>funycat_02</name>
      <category>funy</category>
      <link>/data/funy/funy_cat02</link>
    </cat>
    <cat>
      <name>funycat_03</name>
      <category>funy</category>
      <link>/data/funy/funy_cat03</link>
    </cat>
</cats>
```

My class :

```
        private string _title;

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }

        private string _picture;

        public string Picture
        {
            get { return _picture; }
            set { _picture = value; }
        }

        private string _category;
        public string Category
        {
            get { return _category; }
            set { _category = value; }
        }

        private List<Catpict> _listpict;
        public List<Catpict> Listpict
        {
            get { return _listpict;}
            set { _listpict = value; }
        }

        public List<Catpict> feed()
        {
            Catpict tempcat = new Catpict();

            var reader = XDocument.Load("Data/DataFile.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> cats = reader.Elements();

            foreach (var cat in cats)
            {
                tempcat.Title = cat.Element("Name").Value;
                Listpict.Add(tempcat);
            }
            return Listpict;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the parsing of my XML.
I want to send into my collection  Listpict all cat in my xml.

The question maybe stupid, and my english is realy bad.

If somebody have some answer for me i'm totally open.

Catpic is my class name.

Comment: It is not clear what `Catpict` is...can you provide more information on that.

Comment: Use XSD.EXE to generate a schema and XSD2Code to generate classes from that schema, it will be far easier for you.

Comment: Catpict is my class name. sorry.

Comment: @user3612819 update your post to show the `Catpict` class definition. Also is the `feed` method what you have tried or pseudo code of what you want? That is unclear.

Comment: My english is pretty bad that why i don't explain a lot Omega sorry for that.
For explain what i'm trying to do : 
I'm doing a offline windows phone 8 application (for get some experience of developpement in this device.)
I store some picture into a folder like Data/catpicture or something like dat. And i make a xml for structure this. (what you see) I use it like a little database.

What i try to do here is to deserialize my xml into a list of object Catpict.I don't know if it clear but i do my best for explain. (ps: actually i'm trying to do it with json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this...

```
    public static List<CatPict> feed()
    {
        CatPict tempcat = new CatPict();
        string xml = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml").ToString();

        using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //put your logic here
            }
        }
        return Listpict;
    }
```